# How can i make links to the worldwideweb (www) from my local site in my localhost?

Tags: html, hyperlink, localhost, anchor

I am doing a school project regarding a small website that uses php. I have some links though that point outside my site, i.e www.facebook.com

The problem is that the best i got to is : localhost/www.facebook.com which results in Object noy Found!

```
 <a href="../www.facebook.com">Contact me!</a>
```

How can i make links to the worldwideweb (www) from my local site in my localhost?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 because I haven't heard the term "world wide web" in approximately forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Contact me!</a>
```

Comment: And if you want to force them to open in other ways (new tab, new window, etc.), take a look at the `target` attribute.

Comment: +1 Just like cantillon answered, don't try to make the link relative to the current directory and just make href property equal to the actual link.